# window.chrome.cast not available on Android Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, chromecast

**Background**

In order to initialize a Chromecast session from my video player, I need to call a method on `window.chrome.cast`. This works correctly on desktop Chrome, however Android Chrome's `window.chrome` object does not include the requisite `cast` field.

I am using a Google Pixel running Android 9. Your advice is appreciated!

**The code**

Before initializing the Chromecast session, I add a listener on the window that detects whether the Google Chromecast API is available:

```
window.__onGCastApiAvailable = (isAvailable) => {
    if (isAvailable) {
        this.initializeCastApi();
    }
};
```

On Android Chrome, `isAvailable` does not become true and thus the API is never initialized. If I remove the conditional and just run `initializeCastApi()`, the following line is the first to run in that method:

```
const sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(/* App ID */);
```

On Android, this causes the following error, since `window.chrome.cast` does not exist:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SessionRequest' of undefined
```

**Expectations vs reality**

I expect the Chromecast behavior on Android Chrome to function as it does on desktop Chrome, since the Chromecast API is available on both.

However the `window.chrome` objects are not the same, and since Android's object does not include `cast`, I am unable to launch Chromecast on that browser.

**Screenshots**

The `window.chrome` object on desktop Chrome (notice the presence of `cast`):
[image]

And the `window.chrome` object on Android Chrome:
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Running into the same problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

The Presentation API which contains Chromecast [isn't available over HTTP anymore](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1306336).

Try loading your web sender over a HTTPS connection.

The easiest way to do that is by using ngrok;

1. Install [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
2. Run `ngrok http 3000` (replace `3000` with your local port)
3. Navigate to the forwarding address with `https` displayed in the terminal